# QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loadedQSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm new  here 
I want to run this  code :

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
teste w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

when I try to run it   I become this fault

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

I have window7, 32 bit System , Msql 5.1.72, qt.5.1.1, visual Studio 2010

Any advice please ?

Comment: You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62029610/9617615). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error message hints that you have missed the `QMYSQL` plugin. You may take a look at [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows) on how to build it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is  only need to Copy `libmysql.dll` from `%mysql%\lib` to `C:\Windows`