# After build and install MySql driver for Qt it's unable to load the MySql Drive

Tags: windows, qt, mysql-connector

I'm already build and install the MySql drive [like here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv3wK.jpg). But still I got the error message QMYSQL driver not loaded. Now it;s say MySql as a available driver. I'm using 64bit windows, Qt creator version 32-bit, mingw81_64 and MySql 64 bit Error is,

" QMYSQL driver not loaded. available drivers: QSQLITE QMARIADB QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7"

Comment: See that space at the beginning.  I am suspicious. If you load the driver with a string check for a leading space.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have the libmysql.dll (or libmariadb.dll) in your path. The mechanism is that the MySQL database plugin dll is dynamically loaded runtime, and even if the database plugin itself is present (therefore listed as available), it might fail to load if the libmysql.dll (or libmariadb.dll) is not found.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you please explain What is the path?

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47334605/9617615). Enough details are provided there.
In brief:

1. Download proper libmysql.lib based on your Qt creator version (32-bit?)
2. Put that dll in your build directory (to see your project's build directory, click the "Projects" button on the left menu bar on Qt creator and see the "Build directory")
3. Build and run

***Edit 1:***

One more thing: when you download different versions of libmysql.dll, do as follows:

- Right click on your application project and select "Add Library"
- A dialog opens. Select "External library" radio button and click "Next"
- For the "Library file", brows for your libmysql.lib and select it
- In the "Platform" section, select the proper platform (windows, linux, ...)
- If you are a windows user, make sure to check the "Library inside "debug" or "release" subfolder" checkbox
- Click next

This is the most reliable way to add a library to your project. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm  using 64bit windows, Qt creator version 32-bit, mingw81_64 and MySql 64 bit. Is there any problem?

Comment: No, there is no problem. Did you follow the above steps? I had the same problem and finally solved by testing different versions of libmysql.dll. I wrote you some other things in my answer. Please see "Edit 1".

Comment: Thaanks. I'll try it

Comment: Is that libmysql.lib or  libmysql.dll ?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. You have to select libmysql.lib.

Comment: Let me know your email. I'll send you a simple example.

Comment: geotetest@gmail.com

Comment: I sent to you a simple example. I could regenerate "driver not loaded" error by removing the libmysql.dll file. But once you copy it in the build directory that error removes. Please notice that in my example, I've assumed that you have MySQL Workbench software installed on your machine, and hence I've set the host name as "127.0.0.1" in my example. If so, the example will run perfectly without any error. But if you have not MySQL installed on your machine, then you may face new errors after the "driver not loaded" error removes.

Comment: Please notice that as the Google does not allow to send executable files via email, I sent my example through a dropbox link and the download link will expire after a couple days.